# sharepoint services list to json

Tags: json, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint Services 3.0 and I would like to download from list a simple record, to be specific, a date, beacuse I want to create automatic mailing notification for every record with date. Is there any way to convert this list records to i.e JSON?

Comment: use rest.. https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest you need to get your accesstoken and than do a http request

Comment: @Unlockedluca [SharePoint Services 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931737(v=office.12).aspx) is an on-premises product (it's the free version of SharePoint 2007). It predates SharePoint Online and it has no REST endpoints.